# A2Lix - Column positions

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, a2lix-translation

is there any way I can rearrange field positions in edit/create form in Sonata Admin?

Something like that:

$formMapper->add('translations','a2lix_translations',array(
   'fields'=>array(
         'title' => array();
     )
);

$formMapper->add('position');

$formMapper->add('translations','a2lix_translations',array(
   'fields'=>array(
         'subtitle' => array();
     )
);

Answer (score 0):

You have to install sortable bundle - https://packagist.org/packages/pixassociates/sortable-behavior-bundle. There is also a tutorial how to implement that in Sonata Admin.

You should also enable sortable (https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sortable.md) by adding variable into Entity like:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\SortablePosition
 * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
 */
private $position;
```

After that you will have something like that in your admin:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to rearrange records in database, but the fields in edit/create form. :)